# Current time in blackberry

Tags: networking, time, blackberry, system

Hi I need to know how can I get current time in blackberry if I change the device time
I am using system.getcurrenttimemillis() method

Is it possible ???
Or concept of network time comes into this

Answer (score 0):

`System.currentTimeMillis` gives you a timestamp in [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC), which is roughly the time in the Greenwich Meridian.

If your time is updated via network or changed in settings then the returned value changes as well.

Comment: As per my knowledge it takes device time... if I change the time or date in bb device ... will it still give current date or time  which is present or the date /time of device

Comment: Answer is yes, but of course you could have figured that out for yourself if you had tried it....